Import bootstrap
I am using React and when I make
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.css'; 
Index.css don’t work, but when I delete bootstrap import,  Index.css work again, but I can't use reactstrap
I want them both
And thanks!

Try to import bootstrap in your index.css file.
@import url('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');

